# GoDaddy-Drupal Site down due to mysql password change, how to change it back?

Tags: web-hosting, htaccess, mysql, drupal, godaddy

PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'lev1127301002684'@'188.121.41.131' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /home/content/69/8327469/html/includes/lock.inc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look for `sites/default/settings.php` via ftp and update the following line `mysqli://mysite:password@123.456.789.123/mysite’` replacing your old password with the new one.

Comment: Thanks i have fixed that now i have one more..  this error can be found at [link](http://www.levencruisingclub.com)                               `Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_views_base_tables() in /home/content/69/8327469/html/sites/all/modules/calendar/includes/calendar.views.inc on line 18`

Comment: This should help you out http://drupal.org/node/1460214

Comment: As said in the link provided commenting out line 18 `$base = array_keys(date_views_base_tables());` fixed the issue and i can now access my admin section to update to the latest release. Thank you for the assistance

Comment: @kyle happy to help